# qtip2 styling is not changing

Tags: html, css, qtip

I have a text and i want to make a tooltip for this text thats for i wrote this code :

```
<ul id="more">
   <li><a title=" Christophe is a Senior Technical analyst on the FX and Money Markets Research Desk.
 ">CHRISTOPHE CHEVALIER</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#more').on('mouseenter', 'a[title]', function (event) {
        $(this).qtip({
            overwrite: false,
            show: {
                event: event.type, 
                ready: true
            }
    });
});
</script>
```

The tooltip is shown but i want to change the style of this tooltip i used the custom styles but no changes any help please?
i want to change the style of the tooltip for a sugar eye per example or bubbles or any different style than a simple block of text .

Comment: Can you add a fiddle or something? Do you use qtip2? If so, you can use the _style_ option `$('.selector').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'I\'m blue... deal with it!'
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'qtip-blue qtip-shadow'
    }
});`

http://qtip2.com/options#style

Comment: after the code test only the title is showing their is no tooltip activation i included the css and js cdns . what else should i do to activate this tooltip

Comment: Can you add your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ ?
Have you included jquery and qtip?

Comment: i have added 3 of them: jquery.qtip.css ,jquery.min.css and jquery.qtip.js

Comment: Please create a fiddle so I can check, what's the problem. Maybe it's just the order of the files? Can you check if you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not definede.id @ jquery.qtip.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ jquery.qtip.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ jquery.qtip.min.js:4
qtip.html:42 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: Have you included jQuery in the right version? Try this: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js

Comment: yes i did but no changes , this is the link of the original code but on my local machine it dosent work.(http://jsfiddle.net/qTip2/qcwV4/)

Comment: Just try using the exact same versions like in the fiddle. Can you test using it on a server (not local)?

Comment: i am testing it on my local machine , can u provide me with all the required cdns?

Comment: Just check the fiddle: http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/jquery.qtip.js
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/jquery.qtip.css

Comment: its not logic whats happening i used all the required cdns but nothing happens  can i have ur skype id to contact u on skype?

Comment: those are my cdns : <head>
  <title>Tooltip</title>
        
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/jquery.qtip.css" />
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/qtip2/2.2.1/jquery.qtip.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        </head>

Comment: it was cdns order :) i fixed the problem thank u for ur help